# What day of the week will be $1993^3$ days from Sunday?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Can anyone show me how to solve this problem in a simple way?

> What day of the week will be $1993^3$ days from Sunday?

Here is what I did: $1993^3=7916293657.$ $7916293657$ is divisible by $7$, so the answer should be Sunday. First the answer is wrong, second there must be a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: Divide 1993 by 7 and take the remainder *before*. 1993 is not divisible by seven.  If has remainder 5.  So 1993^3 will have the same remainder as 5^3.  Note 1993 = 1400 + 593=1400+490+103=1400+490+70+33=140+490+70+35-2=7M-2.  (7M-2)^3= some monster multiple of 7 -8=smmo7 -7 -1=7N-1.  So the answer is saturday.

Answer (score 3):

$$1993 \equiv 5 \mod 7$$

$$5^3 \equiv (-2)^3 \equiv -8 \equiv -1 \mod 7$$

Hence, it is a Saturday.